# Is it possible to connect two separate nodes by two links?

Tags: netlogo

I am wondering if it is possible to do this as I am trying to build a traffic simulation model and may need to utilise this feature , should it exist, in my model.

Comment: please elaborate your question, give the code you tried etc

Comment: ask circle 0 [create-links-with n-of 1 circles with [color = read-from-string connect-with]

Comment: I then proceeded to replace 1 with two and in the input box in the u.i inserted only one other colour of node to which once 0 could attach

Answer (score 2):

There two, and only two, conditions under which a pair of turtles may be connected by more than one link:

- If the links are directed, you can have two links, going in opposite directions.
- If the links are different breeds.

You might consider alternatives like having a single link but adding a `links-own` variable to the links containing a weight, count, or other information.